# How turn On/Off android display backlight using C# only in Unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, screen-brightness, backlight

Anybody knows how to turn On/Off android display backlight using C# only in Unity? I don't like plugins, and I don't want to make one of my own.
I know that you can disable the display while using the proximity sensor... but i don't know how to do it in C# in Unity3d...

Maybe the **android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS** will help but i don't know how to change the value (1-255) in Unity3d with C#
If someone have a solution i would be very happy.
thank you
M.

Comment: Read the Unity's doc about `AndroidJavaObject` and `AndroidJavaClass` then try to port that Java code to C# with the classes I mentioned above. If you run into issues, edit your question, add the Java code you trying to port then add the C# code you wrote with `AndroidJavaObject` and `AndroidJavaClass` that didn't work. You will get help from many Unity users here otherwise it looks like you waiting for someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

i've try'ed this but i did not get any result...

```
   public void CheckScreenBrightness()
{
    using (var actClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
    {
        var context = actClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS");
        AndroidJavaClass systemGlobal = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings$Global");

        var screenbrightness = systemGlobal.CallStatic<int>("getInt", context.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver"), "SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS");

        Debug.Log("Screen Brightness = " + screenbrightness);
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-get-property-from-settings-system.458807/, maybe it will help